# Will there be an Ask Ubuntu Google+ Community?

Tags: discussion, community, google+

Google+ has recently rolled out [Communities](http://www.google.com/+/learnmore/communities/). Will there be a Community for Ask Ubuntu? Would it be a good idea, and if so, how should it be used?

There is already an [Ask Ubuntu Fan Page on Google+](https://plus.google.com/b/107921963368679288414/), but this would be different. Pages and Communities allow for different kinds of interaction, and some projects I've seen on Google+ have both a Page and a Community.

Answer (score 9):

We already have a Google+ Page, Chat, Meta, and IRC Channel, and several others. I don't see how adding a Google+ Community will really. In addition due to trademark policies we'll never be able to have an "Official Ask Ubuntu Community" on G+ since it's a Stack Exchange property (hence the Ask Ubuntu Google+ *Fan* page). IMO it's best to just join the Ubuntu Google+ community and discuss there.

In addition, this just becomes another noise box. IMO, it would be FAR better to create a sub-topic under the Ubuntu Community for Ask Ubuntu. That way the entire Ubuntu G+ community doesn't have to join yet-another-community on Google+. That being said I would ONLY want this to be a sub-topic on the Ubuntu Community if there was actual *real* demand for it. Not just want, but a demand. The same reason I've given for why we shouldn't have an Ask Ubuntu blog, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I've made a community here: [Ask Ubuntu G+ Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/115855603775061567076)

I'll add all the moderators as moderators there. I need permission from @JorgeCastro to make it official

**Discuss on how to use it**:

Comment: I don't have any power to make anything official, maybe ping the community council? Or just the moderators + SE should be enough?